# Display dates in command output in different timezone

Tags: command-line, time, timezone

I have 27 systems those are connected to a server. In that, some systems are in different time zones. So, when a person turned on the system for the first time in the day, I need to find the login time of the user in IST but it is showing in their respective time zone (BST for example).

I can get the info by using `w` or `who`. How can I get the time in IST without changing the time-zones of those client systems?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! What do you mean by “system login time”? Is it something reported to your server? Or do you want to switch timezone for a particular task on the clients? Please [edit] your question to explain.

Comment: I have 27 systems those are connected to a server. in that, some systems are in different time zones. so, when a person turned on the system for the first time in the day I need to find the login time of the user in IST but it is showing in their respective time zone.

Comment: i can get the info by using "w" or "who"  command

Comment: root@ve22:/test# who
jyotsna.v :0           2018-09-11 09:20 (:0)
root     pts/6        2018-09-11 11:29
from above I can get the time but it is not showing in IST

Comment: So do you just want to adjust the output of the `who` and `w` commands? Or change the displayed timezone for a particular user of those client machines? Please [edit] your question to add all the details you posted in comments. It helps to keep our Q&A style tidy and could also bring more attention since an edited question gets bounced on the homepage.

Comment: yes but I don't want to change the System Time Zone.

Comment: @Venki comments are intended to help you improve the question for future readers, not for conversation. Please edit your question instead of burying important information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the timezone for a particular command you are running on the remote machine by prepending `TZ=<name>`. Example (my server is using [CEST](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cest), UTC+2):

```
$ who
mirek    pts/0        2018-09-12 14:07 (192.168.2.82)
$ TZ=UTC who
mirek    pts/0        2018-09-12 12:07 (192.168.2.82)
```

Unfortunately, `TZ=IST` is not supported on my machine (the timezone name is ambiguous according to [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ist)) but you can enter an explicit shift (the +/− sign seem to have inverse meaning in comparison to standard timezone notation):

```
$ TZ=UTC-5:30 who
mirek    pts/0        2018-09-12 17:37 (192.168.2.82)
```

or a city:

```
$ TZ="Asia/Taipei" who
mirek    pts/0        2018-09-12 20:07 (192.168.2.82)
```

If you log in as a particular, specialized user to the remote clients, you can permanently set the `TZ` environment variable in your `~/.profile`.

See also:

- https://superuser.com/questions/164339/timezone-conversion-by-command-line
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables